# Quarkus dependency injection

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have created a service class which is using RedisDataSource. This service class is injectable to resource class and can be accessed through routes defined in it. But this service class can not be used as an api call. It is giving error object can not be initialize, although I am using same @Inject annotation here as well.

Service Class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public final class RedisCacheService {

    /** The val commands. */
    private final ValueCommands<String, String> valCommands;
    
    /** The key commands. */
    private final KeyCommands<String> keyCommands;

    /** Instantiates a new redis cache service.
     *
     * @param ds
     *            the ds */
    public RedisCacheService(RedisDataSource ds) {
        valCommands = ds.value(String.class);
        keyCommands = ds.key();
    }

    /** Gets the.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key
     * @return the string */
    public String get(String key) {
        return valCommands.get(key);
    }

    /** Sets the.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key
     * @param bo
     *            the bo */
    public void set(String key, String bo) {
        valCommands.setex(key, 100, bo); // Expires after 1 second
    }
    
    /**
     * Del.
     *
     * @param key the key
     * @return the uni
     */
    public int del(String key) {
        return keyCommands.del(key);
    }

    /**
     * Keys.
     *
     * @return the uni
     */
    public List<String> keys() {
        return keyCommands.keys("*"); 
    }
}
```

Resource Class which is working with route /increments:

```
@Path("/increments")
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    RedisCacheService service;
    
    @GET
    public List<String> keys() {
        System.out.println("****************Calling redis keys***********************");
        return service.keys();
    }

    @POST
    public Cache create(Cache increment) {
        System.out.println("****************Calling redis1 create***********************");
        service.set(increment.key, increment.value);
        System.out.println("Stored data in cache");
        return increment;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{key}")
    public Cache get(String key) {
        System.out.println("****************Calling get***********************");
        return new Cache(key, service.get(key));
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{key}")
    public int delete(String key) {
        return service.del(key);
    }
}
```

Class where need to use as an api (Not working):

```
public class CartService {
    
    @Inject
    RedisCacheService service;

    /** Prepare cart req.
     *
     * @param request
     *            the request
     * @return the json node */
    public JsonNode prepareCartReq(JsonNode request) {
        System.out.println("Before cache call1");
        Cache cacheObj = new Cache("testkey1","testval1");
        service.set(cacheObj.key, cacheObj.value);
        System.out.println("After cache call");
....
}
```

Giving error

> :lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.concentrix.b2b.dell.c2r.helpers.RedisCacheService.set(String, String)" because "this.service" is null

Comment: How is `CartService` instantiated?

Comment: It is getting called through camel route

Comment: from(direct("addToCartRoute")).routeId("addToCartRouteId").marshal().json()
              .choice().when((simple("${header.audit-tag}").isNull()))
                .setHeader(CommonConstants.AUDIT_TAG).method(TagGenerator.class, "generateTag()").end()
                .method(CartService.class, "prepareCartReqPath(${body})").setProperty(CommonConstants.URL).simple("{{addToCartService.url}}")
                .setBody().method(CartService.class, "prepareCartReq(${body})").to("direct:dellServiceRoute").unmarshal().json();

Comment: Well, then the Camel route probably doesn't obtain the instance from the CDI container. I don't know anything about Camel, so can't help there -- but the issue clearly is that CDI wasn't used to instantiate the class, so no dependency injection was applied.

Comment: Instead of referring to `.method(CartService.class)`, use the name of the CDI bean. Or just inject `CartService` into the `RouteBuilder` and pass the object reference.